# How to realize an endless Queue in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a table t_user in a MySQL Database with a field "user_isonline". This flag can change for every user every second (done by user interaction on an external website).

Now I would like to realize a nodeJS script, which runs all day, checking if there are users with "user_isonline" = true, if yes put them into a queue and process them somehow.

As I am very new to nodeJS and async programming, I actually have only very few ideas on even how to start.

It would be great to have some slim lines of code and not to use any pre-defined package or something.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the setTimeout Function which Node provides you could create a timer which queries the database if something has changed (i.e. Query for isOnline and attach the new users to your queue)

More details about setTimeout: [Timers Doc NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/)